Can you deduce the size of a residue field of a number field with a $P$-adic norm based on its degree and $p$ that $P$ lies over?
Let $K$ be an algebraic number field with a $P$-adic norm and $\mathcal{O}_K$ it's ring of integers. We know that by definition $K$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $n$. We also know that $P$ that lies over some prime $p$, i.e. $P \cap \mathbb{Z} = (p)$, so residue field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ has cardinality $p$. Can we deduce the cardinality of the residue field of $K$ from these information?

Should it not be easy to find unramified (over $p$) extensions of the rationals of any degree $f$, i.e. residue field of size $p^f$?

@TorstenSchoeneberg Apologies if I'm not understanding this correctly, I'm relatively new to the algebraic number theory. Does this not guarantee only that there exists an extension of rationals with residue field of this size, rather than that every extension with this degree must have residue field of this size? I presume in the ramified case this would no longer be true, but in the unramified case the size always going to be $p^f$?

I’m not sure what the givens of the problem are. It looks as if you’re telling us $[K:\Bbb Q]=n$ and the natural-number prime $p$, nothing else, and you’re asking what the residue-field extension degree $f_{P/p}$ is. The answer to this question may be, as @TorstenSchoeneberg has suggested, any number at all up to $n$, depending on the particular extension $K$ and the particular primes $P$ and $p$.
